# HTML tags inside <label>

Tags: html, nested, label

I have a table in a page that consists of checkboxes in the cells on the left and descriptions in the cells on the right. The "description" contains h4 headers and plain text. I want to make that whole description (everything inside `<td></td>`) a label.

So each row looks like this:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="entiries[]" value="i1" id="i1"></td>
<td><label for="i1">
<h4>Some stuff</h4>more stuff..
<h4>Some stuff</h4>more stuff..
</label>
</td></tr>
```

This does not work however, the text does not act like a label and is not clickable. I'm using Firefox 3.6 to test it. If I remove `<h4>` tags it starts working, but that complicates formatting. Is there something about `<h*>` tags that prevents `<label>` from working correctly?

Comment: The flag dialog of this very site has `<label>`s with an `<input type="radio">` and two `<span>`s inside, but semantically, the first `<span>` is a heading and the second one is a description, i.e. a paragraph. It’s really unfortunate that such a structure is not possible with the proper HTML tags.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Block level elements (to which `h4` belongs) are not allowed inside inline elements, and will cause undefined behaviour. You can use `span` elements instead.

Comment: block-level elements are not allowed in `span` either.

Comment: Indeed that solves the problem. Setting the style of span to display:block allows me to make it look pretty much the same as a heading (so CSS entry for that span is the same as for h4 + display:block), and the label functionality also works.

Comment: I think he meant "instead of h4s" rather than "instead of labels"

Comment: Yes, I just changed h4 to span and styled spans to imitate h4. Good stuff.

Answer (score 38):

Only [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) (except other label elements) may appear inside label elements.

```
<!ELEMENT LABEL - - (%inline;)* -(LABEL) -- form field label text -->
```

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

It doesn't make sense to put headings there anyway.

Comment: It's not a judgement on you or your project, it's about the semantics of the tags. Semantically, a 'label' element is like a heading for one and only one control. So it's already a heading. Putting another heading inside is redundant. Plus, 'H*' headings can point to many things, but in a label would only be allowed to point to one thing, the same thing that the label is already pointing to. It's like using a heading as the caption for an image. It doesn't make sense semantically. In terms of the look though, it might make sense to use a 'span' tag that is visually similar to an 'H*' tag.

Comment: How about a radio button labeled with an entire multi-section article?  There's really no limit to how much meaning can be associated with that one little circle.

Answer (score 23):

The `<label>` element in HTML is an inline level element and cannot contain block level elements.

This is probably what's causing your issues. Alternatively you can put your labels inside the `<h4>`'s :

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="entiries[]" value="i1" id="i1"></td>
<td><
<h4><label for="i1">Some stuff</label></h4>more stuff..
<h4><label for="i1">Some stuff</label></h4>more stuff..
</label>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: You know, it never occurred to me that you can have more than one label for a given checkbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here on MDN they explain exactly why NOT to use headings inside a label tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#headings):

> Placing heading elements within a  interferes with many kinds of assistive technology, because headings are commonly used as a navigation aid. If the label's text needs to be adjusted visually, use CSS classes applied to the  element instead.