# Is using a HTML Label to wrap elements semantic?

Tags: html, validation, semantics

I'm considering using a `label` to wrap a `h3` and a `p` tag. In my mind this makes sense as the label has a heading and description and both relate to the input. However I can't seem to find any info in the spec on whether this can be done.

Here is an example:

```
<label for="test1">
    <h3>Label Heading</h3>
    <p>Label Description</p>
</label>

<input id="test1" name="test" type="radio"/>
```

If it's not does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Does it validate in W3C Validator?

Comment: Don't conflate validity with semantics. They are different things.

Comment: Indeed - and before you can talk about semantics you need to first make sure the fragment in question is valid. In this case, it's quite simply not valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pasting the following code in the [W3 HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org) yields two errors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="test1">
            <h3>Label Heading</h3>
            <p>Label Description</p>
        </label>
        <input id="test1" name="test" type="radio"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **Element h3 not allowed as child of element label in this context.**
>
> **Element p not allowed as child of element label in this context.**

So this code is rather invalid.

I would also say that is *semantically* "invalid" (or at least weird), because I think of a label as a description for the input box, and a heading does not fit there.

Answer (score 1):

As per W3c they suggest not to use a block element inside a inline element. As label is inline element and Headings and paragraphs are block elements.

Comment: Those are not “suggestions”, they are _rules_. And btw., HTML5 does not simply differentiate between inline or block any more, but has introduced several content _categories_ instead: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#kinds-of-content

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to replicate a [`fieldset` and `legend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Example_1_Form_with_fieldset_legend_and_label) on a per-input basis.

What you probably want is [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-describedby).

```html
<label for="emailInput" id="email-address-label" aria-describedby="email-address-label-description">Email</label>
<span class="label-description" id="email-address-label-description">This will also be your login username</span>
<input type="email" id="emailInput" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="off" autocomplete="email" inputmode="email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to validate your HTML/CSS and others code, there's a great and official website for it :

[W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

You can check just by specifying your website address or copy-paste the source-code.

Beyond the preferences of each person, you'll have the assurance to get tested by the "ruler" (Don't know how to say it) when talking about WWW.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4461959/4637793) should describe to you why you shouldn't write like that.

You could use `<span class="labelHead"></span> <span class="labelDescription"></span>` inside the label-tag, but I wouldn't recommend it.

The best would be to write `<h3>...</h3><label for="...">...</label><input..`.

Except for screen-readers, robots and similar, the `for` attribute is only used to make the text clickable to get focus on the input field, right?